# Passing React Helmet stringified HTML tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I'm trialing a specific way of using React-Helmet to easily manage Meta across multiple pages/sections of an SPA. And want the option to pass tags as strings in certain scenarios.

**Base idea**

1. I have a meta.js file, rendering from a config:

```
export default ({ metaConfig }) => {
    return (
        <Helmet>
            <title>{metaConfig.title}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={metaConfig.description} />
            {...Removed a heap of tags for simplicity}
            {metaConfig.custom}
        </Helmet>
    );
};
```

I've added the custom array, so that you can slot extra scripts/tags into the HEAD on a route by route basis.

This works fine when you have an array of HTML Elements:

```
custom: [
  <meta name="custom" content="Custom content" />
]
```

But obviously doesn't work as an array of strings, which i'd like the ability to include.

Any simple solutions to this?

Comment: thats because strings with `<script />` are sanitised before set. use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with empty `<Fragment />` tag. Refer - https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: never seen dangerously set with an empty fragment... interesting idea haha I would have though this would transfer into a <div> tag

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an easy way I guess, but would like any better suggestions

In the metaConfig file i'll define custom objects like so:

```
custom: [
  <script>This is a standard html element</script>,
  {
    tag: 'script',
    content: `This is a custom element`
  }
]
```

And simply return or create a new element in the meta.js file when rendering through them:

```
{metaConfig.custom && metaConfig.custom.map(meta => {
    return meta.tag 
      ? React.createElement(meta.tag, meta.props, meta.content)
      : meta;
})}
```